# Call CDN delivered library in Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I am trying to interact with the [HelpScout beacon](https://www.helpscout.net/embed-tools/) via their [API](https://developer.helpscout.com/beacons/javascript-api/) methods however struggling to interact with the DOM from the controller.

I have tried running functions such as

```
document.HS.beacon.ready(function() {
  // Open the Beacon as soon as it's ready
  this.open();
});
```

on various lifeCycle hooks such as `ngAfterViewInit()` however, I get a number of errors in the compiler for as `HS` is not a property on `document`.

There are numerous component based JS frameworks that must have a robust solution for interacting with libraries that are delivered via CDN? I would rather they packaged up the code and ran it as an `npm / yarn` package, however that is not the case.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I note that they are simply injecting this code : https://djtflbt20bdde.cloudfront.net. I might just run this locally? Ideas?

Comment: I imagine that your code has `document` spelled correctly, as opposed to this snippet?

Comment: typo, it's correct in my js.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could init the `Beacon` object via `script` tag, that creates an instance of the `Beacon` object as a property of `window`. If you need to interact with this object inside an Angular component or service, you should declare it first (in my case, I needed to destroy the Object):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare let Beacon: any ;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 closeBeacon(){
  Beacon('destroy');
 }
}
```